# multiple connection to the mysql database from a node server, how to fix

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "***",
    password: "***",
    database: "***"
});

    case 'customer.updated':
      //il cliente ha aggiornato indirizzo mail nel portale e io devo fare lo stesso
        con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Connected!");
          var sql = "UPDATE utenze SET email='"+data.object.email+"' WHERE stripe_customer='"+data.object.id+"'";
          con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Customer record updated");
          });
        });
```

With the following code I perform normally the first query after the node server starts. The second query will throw the following error:

> Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.

I understand the meaning of the error and I know I have to fix the concurrent connections that I am doing in parallel to MySql. What I don't understand is how I have to rewrite the code since I am still learning with node.

I have also read that establishing a connection pool can fix the issue (probably because it will not complain if I open two connections for the same query) but is it usefull to implement it while fixing the error?

Comment: Be aware of the SQL injection vulnerability. **Always** use parametrized queries.

Comment: @Alejandro yes, thanks. This is a simplified code for the issue. The production environment is all with parametrized queries.

Comment: Use con.connect once and pass the connection around when you want to make a query. This way you create the connection only once. In your code snippet you create a connection each time.

Comment: @RajikaImal yes I know that’s the issue as I wrote in the question. My qquestion is how I do that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say since the code is not the complete controller, but looks like `con` is global and you're running `con.connect()` every time there's an incoming request. You should `con.connect()` only once. Thus, the first time works, and the second time gives you "already handshaken" error.

Try changing to connection pool, then it's easier to spot where you reserve a connection and where you release it back to the pool.

Comment: Yes. Con is defined globally and used in different places around. How do I rewrite the query part to avoid calling con again? That’s my question

Comment: @LelioFaieta maybe change the implementation to use connection pool, and get back to us if it still doesn't work

Comment: Your answer is not adding any byte of information to what I have already put in my question.